# change sqlinstance for tfs

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

i am encountering a very strange error on the my tfs server. I have a server on which i'm hosting the tfs instance and a server in witch i'm hosting the sql backend for the tfs. The thing is that i want to move the sql instance on another server, a task which i have done once before, and for some reason the tfs server doesn't want to cooperate.

The actions i have undertaken till now are: i've installed sql server 2012 on the my new server, i have moved the databases to the new server(backup - restore), and bow i'm trying to make the chance in the tfs administrative console and for some reason it doesn't work. I have stopped iis `iisreset \stop`, i have stoped the tfs `net stop TfsAgentJob` and when i try to run 'tfsconfig prepsql /sqlinstance:servername' or  `tfsconfig prepsql /sqlinstance:servername\instancename` it gives me the following error:

`CreateTfsExecRole.sql Block #1 Error: TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are not blocking communication with the server.`.

The thing is that the network shouldn't be the problem. I can ping the new sql server from the tfs server and i can connect to the sql server from other servers and i just don't understand the error. I have also tried to the command with the firewall disabled and still the same result. I's there something new in sql 2012 that has to be configured in order for this to work ?

Comment: When you say you're able to connect to the SQL server from other servers, do you mean via Management Studio? Is the SQL instance the default instance or a named one?

Comment: @Chris Yes i connected via Management Studio form other SQL servers and it worked just fine. The new SQL instance is the default instance.

Comment: Is it running on the default port? Can you telnet to that port from the TFS server?

Comment: Yes it is running on 1433 and I tested with telnet and it worked. Also I changed to 1434 and tried because I read someware that it worked on that specific port but sadly I got the same result.

Comment: Weird. I wonder if the error is misleading and it could be a rights issue? Does the account that you're running the command as have sysadmin rights on the instance? I suspect you're going to say yes but I thought I'd ask anyway :-)

Comment: That I'm not sure, now that I think about it. I'll have to check that tomorrow first thing in the morning. But i thought I'd receive a different kind of error if it was something about permissions. I'm really hoping you are right and the error was misleading cause that would save me a whole lot of troubles :)

Comment: Thank you for your guess, you were right. I changed this morning and it worked like a charm. I still hate the error because it was very misleading but I'm glad you pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Good stuff, I'll put this in as an answer if you'd be so kind as to accept it :-) It'll hopefully help someone else in the same position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if the error is misleading and it could be a rights issue? Ensure that the account you're running the `tfsconfig` command as has sysadmin rights on the SQL instance.